# Using CHANGETABLE() in SSDT Visual Studio 2019 results in unresolved reference to object

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2016, sql-server-data-tools, change-tracking

I'm in the process of migrating a bunch of existing databases to a Visual Studio project so it can be put in source control. Unfortunately there is 1 stored procedure which uses a table on which change tracking is enabled. It contains a left join to the following nested select statement:

```
(select distinct ch.batch_number from CHANGETABLE(CHANGES dbName.dbo.batchTable, 0) as ch)
```

This gives the following warning:

> SQL71562: Procedure: [dbo].[stMergeBatchInfo] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [CT].[batch_number] or [CT].[ch]::[batch_number].

It indicates that the column ch.batch_number is unknown. It appears that when the CHANGETABLE function is used the column definition is unknown to the project. The table being read is referenced through a DACPAC file and can be used in standard SELECT statements just fine.
Does anyone know if there any way to get rid of these build warnings? Target SQL server is 2016. The database and table names are dummy names by the way.

Comment: Is `dbName` the current database name? If so, try removing it.

Comment: No, the dbName refers to the database in the DACPAC reference.

Comment: Then you probably want to remove the database reference, as the database name can change based on how you deploy it.

Comment: Not sure I understand this one. The database name is given, it's the same on all environments. Since it's a reference to an object in another database and not in the current project, I am required to put in a database reference. dbName and batchTable are dummy names by the way).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and actually came here looking for an answer. There are 2 things that might help

1. Make sure you have master referenced in your proj. under the proj right click references and add system master.
2. I did a schema compare from the db to the project and noticed my table was missing 'ALTER TABLE [dbo].[History_Table] ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING'

I hope either of these help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately that doesn't help either. I already have the master database added as a database reference, and the table on which change tracking is enabled is inside another referenced database for which we only have a DACPAC. So we're not able to make any changes there.

For now I've decided to ignore this specific warning number by excluding it in the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before.  In my case, the version of the `master` database reference didn't match the version of the Database Project.

In my sqlproj file, the version of the database is 2014 (120).

```
<DSP>
    Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql120DatabaseSchemaProvider
</DSP>
```

Next, ensure your master database reference is the same version (120).

```
<ArtifactReference Include="$(DacPacRootPath)\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\120\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac">
  <HintPath>
    $(DacPacRootPath)\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\120\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac
  </HintPath>
  <SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>
    False
  </SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>
  <DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>
    master
  </DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>
</ArtifactReference>
```

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately both my SQL project and the master DB reference are both set to SQL Server 2016 (130). So that's not fixing it either.